# How to upgrade or use Ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

Sorry for the silly question. But I currently have Ubuntu 12.10. This is because I have an ivy bridge processor and at the time it had the kernel version that supported ivy bridge without freezing/hanging constantly. But I always wanted 12.04 LTS.

My question is: If i was to completely re-intsall the OS (which I want to do) and install 12.04.2, how do I do that? I understand that 12.04.2 is out today but when I downloaded it from the ubuntu main page I only get 12.04.1

Is there any way to get 12.04.2 stable (not daily build) directly? Or at least upgrade 12.04.1 to 12.04.2? I've only found guides on 12.04 -> 12.10

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just wait a day or so; 12.04.2 got major changes (possibly a newer kernel 3.5) in its package. The delay of it's release was due to testing-purposes that got involved.

I feel it's more wise to install 12.04.2 from scratch than to update 12.04.1 , in the end (unless you have a time issue) a little patience could go a long way.

But if 12.10 works fine, why even bother with a 'downgrade' for 12.04 ? You can easily work with 12.10 for more than a year. And in a year a lot can happen (lol) ;) .

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, dot releases are updated automatically with the regular updates to the newest version.

If you want to install 12.04.2, I think you either have to wait a day or so until it is put online (it's probably there in a matter of hours), or download 12.04.1 and update all packages to the latest version.

Comment: Seems like 12.04.2 is officially up at: http://www.ubuntu.com/download - I've just installed it and it runs perfectly fine with IvyBridge (had the same problem as you with the freezing on anything below kernel 3.5x)